# How to replace multiple text substrings in XSLT 1

Tags: xml, xslt

With XSLT 1.0, the regex methods of XSLT 2.0 are generally unavailable. Is there any non-regex way of replacing multiple fields in a node in a source xml document, for example to convert:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" version="1.1">
  <file>
    <source>abc [[field1]] def [[field2]] ghi</source>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" version="1.1">
  <file>
    <source>abc F def F ghi</source>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0 Solution:**

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pTargetStart" select="'[['"/>
 <xsl:param name="pTargetEnd" select="']]'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pReplacement" select="'F'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="source/text()" name="replace">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pTargetStart" select="$pTargetStart"/>
  <xsl:param name="pTargetEnd" select="$pTargetEnd"/>
  <xsl:param name="pRep" select="$pReplacement"/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test=
    "not(contains($pText, $pTargetStart)
       and
        contains($pText, $pTargetEnd)
        )
     or
      not(contains(substring-after($pText, $pTargetStart),
                   $pTargetEnd
                   )
         )
    ">
     <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, $pTargetStart)"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="$pRep"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vremText" select=
     "substring-after(substring-after($pText, $pTargetStart),
                      $pTargetEnd
                      )"/>
     <xsl:call-template name="replace">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$vremText"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pTargetStart" select="$pTargetStart"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pTargetEnd" select="$pTargetEnd"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pRep" select="$pRep"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>

  </xsl:choose>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<xliff xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" version="1.1">
    <file>
        <source>abc [[field1]] def [[field2]] ghi</source>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<xliff xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" version="1.1">
   <file>
      <source>abc F def F ghi</source>
   </file>
</xliff>
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 Solution** (just for comparison):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="source/text()">
  <xsl:sequence select="replace(., '\[\[(.*?)\]\]', 'F')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Did you intend to write `version="2.0"`?

Comment: @lwburk: "XSLT 1" is put explicitly in the title -- someone could downvote an XSLT 2.0 solution :)

Comment: @lwburk: I added an XSLT 2.0 solution, including the phrase: "Just for comparison" :)

Comment: I was trying to point out that your 1.0 solution says 2.0, but the comparison is useful, too.

Comment: @lwburk: Oh, I hadn't noticed -- thanks. This obviously remained from an earlier, undeleted code in my XSelerator -- will correct the version now.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I'm trying to understand the condition you are guarding against with `or not(contains(substring-after($pText, $pTargetStart), $pTargetEnd)`.  Is this to make sure that a string like `'abc [[field def'` (where the delimiter is unbalanced) is not processed/replaced?

Comment: @ZacharyYoung: Yes, if there is a starting `[[`, but no following `]]`, then we don't process the text any more and just copy it "as-is".

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful and educational for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

EXSLT has some good functions for you. If you need to replace simple strings, try [str:replace](http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/replace/index.html). An XSLT 1.0 [template implementation](http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/replace/str.replace.template.xsl) is given.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of EXSLT. It's a shame the regex EXSLT functions aren't in my version of `xsltproc` (on Debian) - but it turns out `replace` is :-) - sorry I can't accept 2 answers.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 1**

*I just realized Dimitre's version uses recursion and is quite similar; so my opening sentence seems silly now.*

Here's a version that uses recursion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:variable name="fld-beg" select="'[['"/>
  <xsl:variable name="fld-end" select="']]'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="replacement" select="'F'"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="source/text()">
    <xsl:call-template name="replace">
      <xsl:with-param name="str" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="replace">
    <xsl:param name="str"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($str, $fld-beg) and contains($str, $fld-end)">
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
          <xsl:with-param name="str" select="concat(
            substring-before($str, $fld-beg),
            $replacement,
            substring-after($str, $fld-end))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$str"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`match="source/text()"` matches all the text in 'source' node as one string and passes it to  the named pattern 'replace'.  'replace' looks for occurrences of the beginning and ending delimiters ('[[' and ']]'), and if found splits the text at (and thus ignoring) the delimiters, inserts the replacement string, and passes all that to itself to repeat the process.

I say "split", but given the lack of a real `split()` in XPath 1.0, we can get by teaming up `substring-before()` and `substring-after()`.

Given the text in the source, `'abc [[field1]] def [[field2]] ghi'`, the recursion goes like this, showing how it's split, replaced, and passed:

1. `'abc ' + 'F' +  def [[field2]] ghi'`, passed again into 'replacement'
2. `'abc F def ' + 'F' + ' ghi'`, passed again into 'replacement'
3. since the delimiters are not present, `'abc F def F ghi'` is passed back up to `match="source/text()"`

Here's how it looks with `xsltproc`:

```
$ xsltproc so.xsl so.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.1" version="1.1">
  <file>
    <source>abc F def F ghi</source>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java inside XSL, example for replaceAll:

```
<xsl:template name="replace_all" xmlns:string="java.lang.String">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="pattern"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:variable name="text_string" select="string:new($text)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="string:replaceAll($text_string, $pattern, $replace)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

pattern is a regexp. For further info see: 
[String javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)